# How to filter a list by another list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have two lists A and B of the same length. I want to keep elements in A which are greater than corresponding elements in B. Let `A=[1,5,8], B=[2,4,9],` the result should be [5] because `1<2, 5>4, 8<9.`

I come up with a solution. Let `C=zip A B,` then filter C, finally get result by taking fst of each element in C. It's not so elegant. Is there a simpler way?

Code:

```
map fst (filter (\ x-> (fst x) > (snd x)) (zip a b))
```

Comment: Can you should your code?  Honestly, it sounds like you've composed `filter`, `fst`, and `zip` together pretty easily, how is it not elegant?

Comment: `myFilter xs ys = map fst (filter (uncurry (>)) (zip xs ys))` sounds pretty damn simple. Anyway, something being "simpler" is prone to opinions and probably leads to primarily opinion based answers.

Comment: @Zeta Similar to my solution. I'm wondering whether there is a built-in function to do this.

Comment: @user50874: Hoogle suggests: [no](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[b]+-%3E+[a]).

Answer (score 4):

Your described solution looks fine to me.

An alternative which is not necessarily better:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad

catMaybes $ zipWith (\a b -> guard (a>b) >> return a) list1 list2
```

According to the desugaring of [monad comprehensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#monad-comprehensions) this should also work

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-}

[ a | ( a <- list1 | b <- list2 ), a > b ]
```

... but in practice it does not. It is a pity because I find it quite elegant.
I wonder whether I got it wrong or it is a GHC bug.

Comment: It's not like `[ a | (a,b) <- zip list1 list2, a > b ]` wouldn't do the trick as well!

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's perfectly fine, of course. It boils down to personal taste. If I use `zip` explicitly, I'm more inclined to use `filter` explicitly. If I start using list comprehensions, I tend to stick to them and avoid using library functions. I concur that `zip` is a bit peculiar since it can not be emulated by plain comprehensions, and requires an extension to enable parallel ones (which are unpopular precisely because of that).

Comment: That does look like a GHC bug; whether it is in implementation or documentation I do not know. Lacking that feature seems to make parallel comprehensions less useful...

Comment: Doesn't that need `ParallelListComprehensions` or so?

Comment: @dfeuer In the docs, parallel lists comprehensions of the form `[A | (B | C), S]` seem to be allowed: quoting the desugaring from the docs `D[ e | (Q | R), S ]    = mzip D[ Qv | Q ] D[ Rv | R ] >>= \(Qv,Rv) -> D[ e | S ]`. In practice, GHC (including 8.6.3) only accepts `[A | B | C]` without the final `S`. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=parallellist#monad-comprehensions

Comment: @dfeuer No idea. I didn't report it, but others might have. Maybe it's just a documentation bug, where some planned features are mentioned even if they were not implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on something similar and as a newbie this is the best I came up with:

```
filterGreaterThan xs ys = do (x,y) <- zip xs ys
                             guard (x > y) 
                             return x
```

This solution is easier to reason about than the others. The do notation really shines here.

Comment: This is essentially the same as [leftaroundabout's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017435/how-to-filter-a-list-by-another-list-in-haskell#comment53861334_33018373), with slightly different notation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your code looks but the following function look quite elegant to me:

```hs
greater :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
greater xs = map fst . filter ((>) <$> fst <*> snd) . zip xs

example :: [Int]
example = greater [1,5,8] [2,4,9] -- result is [5]
```

This pattern is well known in the Lisp community as the *decorate-process-undecorate* pattern.

Comment: Where `f <$> fst <*> snd` is just the same as `uncurry f`, which doesn't need additional imports on older versions of GHC.

Comment: Indeed. However, in my humble opinion, `f <$> fst <*> snd` is more understandable than `uncurry f`.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach, not so elegant as (any) of the other approaches, this relies on no explicit zipping and we get the result in one pass,

```
greater :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
greater [] [] = []
greater (x:xs) (y:ys)  
    | x > y     = x : greater xs ys    
    | otherwise = greater xs ys
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generalize this idea nicely, I would recommend looking to [`mapMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe):

```
mapMaybe
  :: (a -> Maybe b)
  -> [a] -> [b]
```

Applying that idea to `zipWith` yields

```
zipWithMaybe
  :: (a -> b -> Maybe c)
  -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithMaybe f xs ys =
  [c | Just c <- zipWith f xs ys]
```

Now you can write your function

```
keepGreater :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
keepGreater = zipWithMaybe $
  \x y -> x <$ guard (x > y)
```

Is it really worth the trouble? For lists, probably not. But something like this turns out to be useful in the context of merges for `Data.Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty similar to @chi's solution with Lists concant:

```
concat $ zipWith (\a b -> last $ []:[[a] | a > b]) as bs
```